# Log value history of a field in an attribute table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, esri-geodatabase

I have activated the editor tracking it shows the created_user (Text), created_date (Date), last_edited_user (Text), last_edited_date (Date).

But is it possible to know the change of value in a particular field.
For Example, I have a field called "**Progress**" in the attribute table, contains some values namely "**not-edited", "In-progress", "Edited"**.

Is it possible to know the history of edits that the value is changed from "**not-edited**" to "**edited**" via any log files in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try activating [versioning](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/overview-of-versioning-in-arcgis-pro.htm) in your Geodatabase, if you have not already.

This creates a table that gets updated for each edit made to the data, for example a geometry is changed or any attribute value creates a timestamp of the change.

That way you can track that kind of desired change

Comment: Yes, the versioning is activated in my Geodatabase. Kindly can you explain more how can I track these change if versioning is activated.

Comment: With versioning you can create historical 'points' in your database, for example daily or weekly, and return to that point whenever you want.
you can also enable Archiving (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/what-is-archiving-.htm)

Comment: oh, ok. That's really helpful.